# How is an Android Activity recreated when the screen is rotated?

Tags: java, android, asynchronous, android-activity

I'm a newbie Android developer. I know that when the screen orientation changes, the Activity is re-created and `onCreate()` is called again. What I couldn't find online, however, is how exactly the original Activity is destroyed. If some code called by `onCreate()` is in the middle of running, does that code just stop, or does the system wait for that code to finish before rotating the screen and calling `onCreate()` again? Thanks.

Comment: Were you satisfied by my answer? Comment below it if you still want some more details...! or if you have not understood anything!

Answer (score 0):

Activity's onCreate() is called everytime when the orientation changes and you should take care of your asynchronous task because the system does not wait, but you can avoid the re-creation of Activity by adding configChanges attribute of Activity in your AndroidManifest file in the activity tag.

`android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation`"

Comment: "you should take care of your asynchronous task because the system does not wait": I am talking about a synchronous task I am running on the UI thread.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [official documentation on configuration changes](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/runtime-changes.html), once a device rotation is detected or the activity is started for the first time,  onCreate() is called; you should assume that for all intents and purposes the onCreate() method will complete its execution before another screen rotation triggers activity recreation. Any code executed in your onCreate() should be done instantaneously since it shouldn't block your UI.

Answer (score -1):

When rotating a screen we call it one of the Configuration Changes, it includes situations such as screen orientation, keyboard availability, and language changes. As quoted from Android official documentation here  `onDestroy()` will be called then `onCreate()`.

> Some device configurations can change during runtime (such as screen orientation, keyboard availability, and language). When such a change occurs, Android restarts the running Activity (onDestroy() is called, followed by onCreate()).

But if there was any code executing on the main thread will have to finish (not other threads) and Android gives you time to save the activity data which you can receive on `onCreate()` when the activity is restarted. It does so by calling the method by calling the method  `onSaveInstanceState()` as explained here in the documentation.

> To properly handle a restart, it is important that your activity restores its previous state through the normal Activity lifecycle, in which Android calls onSaveInstanceState() before it destroys your activity so that you can save data about the application state. You can then restore the state during `onCreate()` or `onRestoreInstanceState()`.

So the whole issues of code in the activity is that it will wait for the code to finish if it were executing on the main thread and if the code taking too slow it may make configuration changes very slow as it is discouraged in the documentation to make huge tasks in the main thread (for instance `http requests`).

This whole answer and descriptions and quotes has been taken from [Android Official Documentation Guide](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/runtime-changes.html), you can visit it for reference and more descriptions on configuration changes.